# when compass save scss file to css file the " @font face ( name, font-file( ) ) " doesn't work properly

Tags: sass, compass

I try to use woff file to change font. Can u guys help me 
why the CSS take the weird numbers after extension

config.rb

```
fonts_dir = "stylesheets/fonts"
```

SCSS

```
@include font-face("caviardreams", font-files("caviardreams-      webfont.woff", "caviardreams-webfont.ttf", "caviardreams-webfont.svg", "caviardreams-webfont.eot") );
```

CSS

```
@font-face { font-family: "caviardreams"; src: url('/stylesheets/fonts/caviardreams-webfont.woff?1436806012') format('woff'), url('/stylesheets/fonts/caviardreams-webfont.ttf?1436806012') format('truetype'), url('/stylesheets/fonts/caviardreams-webfont.svg?1436806012') format('svg'), url('/stylesheets/fonts/caviardreams-webfont.eot?1436806012') format('embedded-opentype');}
```

I guess when compass find the font it gives the url with weird number('?1436806012'), and it doesnt work in the chrome browser.
If you guys need whole code. please tell me

Comment: Did you actually verify that removing the nocache information makes the font work?  It seems more likely that the font isn't being referenced correctly.

Comment: I used the squrrielcode as the compass.org font-face section described, if you know the right wat to covert ttf file to others, please teach me Thank you~

Comment: What I mean is, if you manually edit the CSS to remove the "weird number", does it work?  If not, then you've got the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

If somebody have same problem as I have,

It's probably "config.rb" need to be uncomment relative_assets = "true"

What I mean is **"REMOVE #"** from **#relative_assets = "true"**

but don't do it if you use http_font_dir